In Blazor .NET 8 , where do I load and store user details?
In ASP.NET MVC, I handled the session_start event to load user details and store them in a session variable, so I didn't have to query the database with each page load.
I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Blazor on .NET 8.
I seams like the App.razor is a good place to put my code, since it is executed with each page load - but I don't know if it is the best practice?
My code in App.razor (server code) looks like this (I'm using Windows authentication):
@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        UserDetails details;
        var user = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
        var userId = user.Identity?.Name?.ToLower();
        var result = await BrowserStorage.GetAsync<UserDetails>(userId);

        if (result.Success)
        {
            details = (UserDetails)result.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            GetUserDetailsQuery query = new GetUserDetailsQuery();
            query.UserLogin = await getUserId();
            details = query.Handle();
            await BrowserStorage.SetAsync(userId, details);
        }   
    }
}

But I get an error:

InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time.

How do you guys solve this? Do you query the database for the same info on each page load?

Understand that in Blazor, a "page load" is a pretty rare thing.  This is really for navigating among pages, which you technically NEVER need to do.  But there are many ways to deal with this.  First of all, if your DB is on your server, there's very little penalty for just re-loading the info whenever you navigate.  But if you want, you can use a Scoped or Singleton service to preload the user's data and provide it in any page that injects the service.  If you want per-device settings, you can use local storage.   For something this simple, I might just load the User's info in the Layout page

1.you can't write code in app.razor or mainlayout.razor  to implement this function
2.you can write in the page home.razor Use whether  httpcontext is Null  to determine whether it is the first time to load，but you should write every page
3.you can use In-memory state container service,Here's an example：
1). create a class :StateContainer.cs
namespace StoreDemo
{
    public class StateContainer
    {
        private string? savedString;

        public string UserId
        {
            get => savedString ?? string.Empty;
            set
            {
                savedString = value;
                NotifyStateChanged();
            }
        }

        public event Action? OnChange;

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
}

2). config in program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<StateContainer>();Server-side 
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateContainer>();//Client-side 

3).create a Nested.razor:
@implements IDisposable
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@rendermode InteractiveServer
<h2>userId from children: @StateContainer.UserId</h2>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }
    private UserDetails details;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (httpContext is null)
        {
            StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
            var result = await ProtectedLocalStorage.GetAsync<UserDetails>("userId");

            if (result.Success)
            {
                details = result.Value;
                StateContainer.UserId = details.userId.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                details = new UserDetails
                    {
                        userId = "11",
                        userName = "hua"
                    };
                await ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("userId", details);
            }
        }
    }
 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}

4).create a demo to use Nested.razor
@page "/state-container-example"
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h2>userId from parent :@StateContainer.UserId</h2>

<Nested />

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }
    private string UserId { get; set; }
    protected override  void  OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
       
    }
   
}

5).The results are as follows


JavaScript calls are available only after the component is completely initialized. Hence, calls to interop should be made only after the rendering is complete. i.e. anytime after OnAfterRender is invoked and it is not a first render.
